# Unknown item shown in rqt_graph

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my rqt_graph shown below, the namespace `path_modification` has an oval titled `color` in the namespace. What is this?

I've looked at `rostopic list` and it's neither a topic nor a service running on the network. I've googled around, but I can only find information about the display color of a node in `rqt_graph`, not an item titled "color" in `rqt_graph`.

`rosnode info path_modification` returns:

```
Node [/path_modification]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
 * /path_modification
 * /path_modification/get_loggers
 * /path_modification/set_logger_level

contacting node http://127.0.0.1:44616/ ...
Pid: 11250
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

I don't see anything related to "color" at all in that output. I don't think `rqt_graph` shows rosparams, but I checked `rosparam list` and I don't see "color" in there either. The output of `rosnode list` is:

```
/path_modification
/ramp_planner
/ramp_sensing
/rosout
/trajectory_evaluation
/trajectory_generator
/trajectory_view
```

So it doesn't seem to be a node either. If anyone knows what this is, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249553/unknown-item-shown-in-rqt_graph/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its a bug, been fixed in the source

https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/pull/86

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1